# Facebook Pop up issue - iOS

Tags: ios, facebook, ipad, popup

I am facing a strange issue. 

When after entering correct username and password. If I press the login button twice(with the interval of 2 secs) then the popup disappears. Though when I tap on FB button again It is already logged in with share screen.

If I press it just once then its working fine.

**Expected:**
It takes me to the share screen in the popup after successful login.

Another issue is sometimes my share for the first time after entering username and password does not work.

Though out of 10 it works for 9 times but sometimes after fresh install it just does not post to FB wall.

Any kind of suggestion will really be appreciated.

Comment: I have experienced your issues once.So if you put some code, surely i can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code, which perfectly works for me now.

```
-(void)buttonPressed:(id)sender{
facebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:@"YOUR_APP_ID" andDelegate:self];

 NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        if ([defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"] && [defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"]) {
            facebook.accessToken = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
            facebook.expirationDate = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
        }
if (![facebook isSessionValid]) {
    [facebook authorize:nil];
}else{
[self postWall];
}
// Pre 4.2 support
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url {
    return [facebook handleOpenURL:url]; 
}
- (void)fbDidLogin {
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:[facebook accessToken] forKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
    [defaults setObject:[facebook expirationDate] forKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
    [defaults synchronize];
    [self postWall];
}
-(void)postWall{

    NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   @"https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/",@"link",
                                   @"http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg",@"picture",
                                   @"Facebook Dialogs",@"name",
                                   @"Reference Documentation",@"caption",
                                   @"Using Dialogs to interact with users.",@"description",
                                   @"Facebook Dialogs are so easy!",@"message",
                                   nil];

    [[self facebook] dialog:@"feed" andParams:params andDelegate:self];

}
```

Don't forget to add **YOUR APP ID**.